# Two UITabbar iOS with different UITabBar.Apperance

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have some difficulties with setting `UITabBar` for different `UITabBar`. We have 2 `TabBar` on the same screen, but the sizes of `TabBar` is different.

I need to set this red line with in different places of `TabBar`.

How can I use separate `UITabBar` Appearance for different `TabBars`?

From `AppDelegate.swift` :

```html
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = getImageWithColorPosition(color: UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.33, blue:0.21, alpha:1.0),                                                                                  size: CGSize(width:(self.window?.frame.size.width)!/4,height: 49), lineSize: CGSize(width:(self.window?.frame.size.width)!/4, height:2))
            return true     
}
    
func getImageWithColorPosition(color: UIColor, size: CGSize, lineSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
      let rect = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
      let rectLine = CGRect(x:0, y:size.height-lineSize.height,width: lineSize.width,height: lineSize.height)
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
      UIColor.clear.setFill()
      UIRectFill(rect)
      color.setFill()
      UIRectFill(rectLine)
      let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      return image
}
```

Comment: Why not subclass the UITabBar's and customise them as per you needs

Comment: Where I can found information about how to do this subclass uitabbar?

Comment: thats simple YourClass: UITabBar. If you have both in one controller, you can assign the class type to your outlets.